# How to create a file and write a specified amount of random integers to the file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Very new to Python and programming. The problem is Create a program that writes a series of random numbers to a text file. Each random number should be in the range of 1 to 5000. The application lets the user specify how many random numbers the file will hold. My code so far is as follows:

```
 from random import randint
 import os
 def main ():
     x = int(input('How many random numbers will the fille hold?: '))
     temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'w')
     temp_file.write(str(randint(1,5000)))
  main()
```

I am having trouble implementing the logic for writing a random integer 1-5000 to a file x amount of times(as entered by the user) Would I be using a for statement?

Comment: Yep, you will want a `for` loop somewhere that iterates as many times as the user specifies. At the moment you'll just get a single integer written. _Note_ that opening the file in `w` (write) mode will wipe all the previous contents, so you'll want to think about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
from random import randint
import os
def main ():
     x = int(input('How many random numbers will the fille hold?: '))
     temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'w')
     for _ in range(x):
         temp_file.write(str(randint(1,5000))+" ")
     temp_file.close() 
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
from random import randint 

def main(n):
  with open('random.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for _ in range(n):
      file.write(f'{str(randint(1,5000))},')

x = int(input('How many random numbers will the file hold?: '))
main(x)
```

Opening the file in 'w+' mode will overwrite any previous content in the file and if a file doesn't exist it will create it.

Since python 3 we can now use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#python-f-strings-the-pesky-details) as a neat way of formatting strings. As a beginner I'd encourage you learn these new cool things.

Lastly, using the `with` statement means you won't need to explicitly close the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python package called `numpy`. It can be installed by pip using `pip install numpy`.
Here is a simple code

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.random.randint(1,5000,20)
file=open("num.txt","w")
file.write(str(arr))
file.close()
```

In the 2nd line, the third parameter `20` specifies the number of random numbers to be generated. Instead of hard-coding, take the value from user

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help, using LocoGris's answer i ended up with this code which answers my question perfectly, thank you! I knew I needed the for statement, the _ could be any letter correct?

```
from random import randint
import os
def main ():
     x = int(input('How many random numbers will the file hold?: '))
     temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'w')
     for _ in range(x):
         temp_file.write(str(randint(1,5000)) + '\n')
     temp_file.close() 
main()
```

Comment: instead of answering your question edit your post ^^ the `_` could be any `variable` but since you are not using there any `variable` ... `_` is like void and throw this count away

Comment: or better comment his answer xD